# Passing enum flags in .net core Web API

Tags: enums, asp.net-core-webapi

There is a back-end api on .net core 2.2:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/reviews")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetReviews(GetReviewsRequest request){...}

public class GetReviewsRequest
{
        [Required, FromQuery]
        public ReviewStatus? Status { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum ReviewStatus
{
    Processing = 1,
    Published = 2,
    Declined = 4,
    Rated = 16,
    Unrated = 32
}
```

it works fine with simple queries like

```
/reviews?status=Processing
```

But it does not work when status supposed to include a few flags:

```
/reviews?status=Processing,Published
```

> "enum value 'Processing,Published' is not defined"

What are the ways to make it work?

Comment: Why don't you use binaries instead of sending values? **/reviews?status=Processing** => **/reviews?status=00001** and  **/reviews?status=Processing,Published** => **/reviews?status=00011**

Comment: binaries are easier but they are not informative, people should not care about binary codes when they consume api

Comment: Do you use `GetReviewsRequest ` or `GetUserReviewsRequest`? Do you use asp.net core 2.2 or 3.0 web api?I could not reproduce your problem.